# How do I create an infinite loop with a question that when answered, categorizes the answer into 1 of 3 different arrays?

Tags: c#

I have 3 different categories.
1. Todlers (Age 1-4)
2. Children (Age 5-17)
3. Grownups (Age 18 and above)

I'd like to infinitely loop "Give a number", so that even when all 3 arrays are filled, it still continues. I want the loop to end only when a 0 is typed. (This I seemed to manage)
Only the ten first values have to be stored, any values after the arrays have been filled can be disregarded. (10 values per 3 arrays is 30 values total)

Then I'd like to categorize the ages as explained above. My current age output ('input') remains 0 for every element in each of the 3 arrays. I realise my if-statements aren't being triggered because of "...Length", but how would you recommend replacing that?
I tried "i < 10" but that lead to Array Out of Bounds Exception, as well as putting todlers[i]/children[i]/grownups[i] < 10

Sorry if I am not being concise enough, but I'm still a beginner and English isn't my mothertongue.
Thanks in advance.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] todlers = new int[10];
        int[] children = new int[10];
        int[] grownups = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; ; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Give a number (0 = stop) : ");
            int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (todlers.Length < 10 && input < 5 && input > 0)
            {
                todlers[i] = input;
            }
            else if (children.Length < 10 && input > 4 && input < 18)
            {
                children[i] = input;
            }
            else if (grownups.Length < 10 && input > 17)
            {
                grownups[i] = input;
            }

            else if (input == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("TODLERS");
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Todler {0} is {1} years old", i, todlers[i]);
        }

        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("CHILDREN");
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Child {0} is {1} years old", i, children[i]);
        }

        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("GROWNUPS");
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Man/Woman {0} is {1} years old", i, grownups[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: your arrays are always 10 in length, as such none of the if's trigger.

Comment: yeah I thought as much. How would you suggest fixing it though? I tried putting i < 10 but that leads to an Array Out of Bounds | Also tried todlers[i] < 10 etc but same story there

Comment: You don't need your .Length < 10 check. You have your array set to int[10]

Comment: Your desires are not logically consistent.  If your program loops forever, where will new values be stored?  You should use `List<Int>` instead of `int[]` and you should use a while loop instead of a for loop.

Comment: @Victor I want only the ten first values to be stored, the rest of them should be ignored.

Comment: how do you fill an array with a while loop

Answer (score 1):

The `Length` of your arrays doesn't change, it stays the same as at initialization (10) throughout your program. As a result `todlers.Length < 10` is always false.

Given that you never put `0` inside your arrays you can replace `todlers.Length < 10` with `todlers[9] == 0` that will effectively check that you haven't yet changed the last element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
```

you should change to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

it because you had initialize array with 10 elements and the first one will be 0

todlers[0],todlers[1] ... todlers[9]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List` to store a collection of things when you don't know how many items you will have. Use a `do - while` loop to run a block of code at least once and at most infinitely.

Try something like this (untested code):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Program
{

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    List<int> todlers = new List<int>();
    List<int> children = new List<int>();
    List<int> grownups = new List<int>();
    int input = 0;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Give a number (0 = stop) : ");
        input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (todlers.Count < 10 && input < 5 && input > 0)
        {
            todlers.Add(input);
        }
        else if (children.Count < 10 && input > 4 && input < 18)
        {
            children.Add(input);
        }
        else if (grownups.Count < 10 && input > 17)
        {
            grownups.Add(input);
        }
    }while(input>0);

    Console.Write("\n");
    Console.WriteLine("TODLERS");
    for (int i = 0; i < todlers.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Todler {0} is {1} years old", i+1, todlers[i]);
    }

    Console.Write("\n");
    Console.WriteLine("CHILDREN");
    for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child {0} is {1} years old", i+1, children[i]);
    }

    Console.Write("\n");
    Console.WriteLine("GROWNUPS");
    for (int i = 0; i < grownups.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Man/Woman {0} is {1} years old", i+1, grownups[i]);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

This will stop adding to the lists when there are 10 entries, but the user will have no warning their input is being discarded. It will also only output the number of entries that have been added, instead of zeroes if the user inputs fewer than ten in a category.